# rails devise after_sending_reset_password_instructions weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

i want to redir to a page after sending reset pass instructions, so, by devise docu i added this to my password_controller

```
protected
  def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    'buyers/sign_in'
  end
```

in routes i have the

```
devise_for :buyers, :controllers => { :passwords => "passwords" }
```

and if i add 'puts 'xxxxxxx'' to the function i can even see this output in my server, but it wont REDIRECT to the path i m returning. 
what s the problem?

Comment: Not an issue but you should use rails path helpers in controllers. Can you post your logs?

Answer (score 0):

in the end the problem was due to 'create' func was overloaded and changed severely(also calling super which didn't fit my needs), had to edit it and add this

```
if successfully_sent?(resource)
  redirect_to new_partner_session_path
else
```

for it to work.